# What are FAA rules regarding FBO operations encouraging food/ refreshments for pilots?

Tags: faa-regulations

Specifically chapter, section, paragraph relating to food services for private pilots at an FBO.

Answer (score 10):

It is not within the jurisdiction of the FAA to regulate ground-based food service.

Comment: Wrong. FAA administers Federal airport funding and has the right to regulate services at airports under the threat of withholding such funding. See e.g. [AC 150/5190-7](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/150-5190-7/150_5190_7.pdf), [AC 150/5190-6](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/advisory_circular/150-5190-6/150_5190_6.pdf), [Airport Sponsor and Airport User Rights and Responsibilities](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/airports/airport_compliance/compliance_guidance/airportSponsorAndUserRightsBrochure.pdf).

Comment: @user71659 Neither Advisory Circulars nor the other document you linked to are regulatory per se, and none of the documents you linked is responsive to the OP's question. Yes, the FAA might withhold funds based on an airport's discriminatory policies toward vendors at the airport, but that isn't what the OP is asking about. I think this answer, given the scope of the question, is correct.

Comment: @user71659, I am confident in my answer, but of course I cannot prove a negative.  If you can provide *chapter, section, paragraph relating to food services for private pilots at an FBO* in an answer of your own I will happily concede, delete my answer, and upvote yours.  I trust Ralph's assessment of the applicability of the links you posted and didn't read them myself, but if there is something specific that you think applies to food service please quote it directly.

Comment: AC150/5190-7, says Federally-funded airports must be operated for the benefit of the public, and it is strongly recommended to have a plan and standards for their operation. Specifically refer to 2.1(c)(2)(a) saying plans should be in place for "Access to passenger loading bridges/steps, sanitary rest rooms, boarding hold
rooms, telephones, **food and beverage service, and other passenger concessions.**" This is strictly optional, but if your airport provides poor services, you won't be getting Federal funding.

Comment: @user71659, but you need to consider the context: Section 2 is "*guidance* for developing minimum standards" and contains sample questions for the "airport sponsor" to consider in developing those standards. It does not say that food MUST be provided, nor does it dictate the quality of the food. It is *advisory*, not regulatory, and you admit it is "strictly optional". Besides, withholding funding is not the same as having the authority to actually regulate something. And finally, the specific subsection you referenced is for *passengers*, not pilots.

Comment: If you disagree then please post your own answer, I am confident in mine.